# Turn function into a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I have a variables that I am trying to turn into a lambda function but I am struggling to get the input variable to work in the lambda expression.

My variables are:

```
function_name = 'add'
inpt = 'a,b,c'
```

and I want the output to be `abc * 5` `(a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c)`. However it is important that I use the variables rather than simply typing this.

I have tried to use a dictionary as such:

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict[function_name] =lambda inpt: inpt*5
```

However the output is a lambda function and I still have to manually enter the value of `inpt` instead of it taking the variable.

I am fairly new to programming so I may have misunderstood how the lambda function works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HI geds, Can you post your whole lambda function (I guess you are talking about aws lambda)?

Comment: Show how you want to use the function. You want to supply the data when the function is created instead of called?

Comment: Are you looking for the following a lambda like this `lambda: inpt*5`? It almost seems like you do not even need to give it a parameter.

Comment: `my_dict[function_name](inpt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't give the lambda a parameter:

```
function_name = 'add'
inpt = 'a,b,c'

my_dict = {}
my_dict[function_name] = lambda: inpt * 5  # Don't say that the lambda takes a inpt argument

>>> my_dict[function_name]()  # Now we don't need to supply that here
'a,b,ca,b,ca,b,ca,b,ca,b,c'
```

I'll note that the output isn't technically correct, but that's not the main point here. You could try using `", ".join` on a list of `['a', 'b', 'c']` after using list multiplication to get a better result.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, this is what I needed. One other thing, is there anyway that I am able to print this function in a single line as well e.g. `add = lambda: a,b,c * 5`

Comment: @geds133 What do you mean "print this function"? `print(my_dict[function_name]())`?

Comment: So I recieve the output there `a,b,ca,b,ca,b,ca,b,ca,b,c`, whereas I want to able to print a string in the format `add = lambda: a,b,c * 5`

Comment: @geds133 You want to print out the literal source code?

Comment: Correct, print as a string

Comment: @geds133 [`getsource`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource), although you probably shouldn't need to use that beyond debugging and a few other corner scenarios.

Comment: @geds133 this sounds like it might be a case of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382). Can you provide more context for this particular question?

Answer (score 0):

```
inpt = 'a,b,c'
func = lambda inpt: ''.join(inpt.split(','))
d = tuple(func(inpt*5))
```